# Rounded corners on <td> in Explorer 8 with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, explorer, rounded-corners

Need to get rounded corners on table elements, in this case td-tags in IE8 with JavaScript/jQuery. Not images.

Have tried different solutions. CSS3 Pie only seem to work on div-tags. Also tested Curvy Corners and jQuery.corner.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in IE8, not with JavaScript, the way borders work on `<table>` elements is slightly different to begin with, and very different on `<td>` (how would collapsing behave? which way is the curve?).

IE8 just doesn't support what you want here...you could use images, but then your markup will increase heavily.

Comment: Ok, then I see why. Thanks for your quick question!